# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified while using pytesseract python-3.x

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, pytesser

I am using `pytesseract` to read image as text in python. Following is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string
import os.path

if (os.path.exists('image.png')):
    filename = 'image.png'
    image = Image.open(filename)
    image.show()
    s = image_to_string(Image.open(filename))
else:
    print('Does not exist')
```

The code gets the file `image.png`, opens it and show the image to me which means the file exists in that directory. But when it goes to next line `s = image_to_string(Image.open(filename))` it gives the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/hp/Desktop/GII/Genetic_Algorithm.py", line 8, in <module>
    s = image_to_string(Image.open(filename))
  File "C:\Users\hp\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.2\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 161, in image_to_string
    config=config)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.2\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 94, in run_tesseract
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.2\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\subprocess.py", line 950, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.2\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\subprocess.py", line 1220, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I tried hard but do not know how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try :

f2 = os.path.abspath(filename)

s = image_to_string(Image.open(f2))

PIL is apparently using some subprocess, that may not have the same "default directory" than the main process

Comment: I am getting the same error again. I thinl PIL is not creating problems because I can open the image using Image.open(filename) but if you see the above error it is occuring when I am using `pytesseract`.

Comment: other idea; you open twice the file, so the  second time, the file is unavailable. so, maybe try "s = image_to_string(image)"

Comment: I didn't exactly get what you are trying to say. I think even If I open the file twice it will not change the path problem. Can you please write your intuition. Thanks

Comment: Maybe the "Image.open()" is opening the file in read/write mode, so opening two times the same file, as in your code, is the problem.